# Using multiple Bitmaps in iOS

Tags: ios, bitmap

I am trying to port my code from android to iOS. In android I use to use multiple bitmaps and then transfer them using Xfer mode. How do I achieve the same thing in iOS. I tried

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
```

But not sure how I can get multiple bitmaps to manipulate. May be I am missing something basic. Appreciate all the help.

Comment: Maybe you could give us a clue about what sort of manipulation you want to do? :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a new `CGBitmapContext` to draw to. `CGBitmapContext` is like a subclass of `CGContext`.

I'm not sure what "transfer them using Xfer mode" means; Perhaps you are looking for `CGBlendMode`s?